# Calling the constructor in a function, in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a class, something like

```
class tensor:
    n = 1
    def __init__(self, n):
       self.n = n ;
    def prod(t,sca=1):
       newa = tensor(t.n * sca)
       return newa
```

but when I print prod( tensor(1),3 ) for instance, there is something wrong. It's like the call of the constructor in the definition of the function does not work "newa = tensor(t.n * sca)". How can I call it in the function please ?

Comment: Your `prod` would be fine if it were an standalone function or static method.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is something wrong"? Please paste the exact error message you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

When calling a method of a class, you don't pass an instance of the class. It is passed automatically.

Here's what I think you're trying to achieve.

```py
class tensor:
    def __init__(self, n):
       self.n = n

    def prod(self, sca=1):
       return tensor(self.n * sca)
```

You can then use it like this:

```py
t = tensor(23)
t_scaled = t.prod(2)
print('t:', t.n)
print('t_scaled:', t_scaled.n)
```

Answer (score 0):

`prod` does not need to be an *instance* method. It can be a *static* method:

```
class tensor:
    n = 1
    def __init__(self, n):
       self.n = n ;

    @staticmethod
    def prod(t,sca=1):
       newa = tensor(t.n * sca)
       return newa

t1 = tensor(5)
t2 = tensor.prod(t1, 3)
```

Or it can be a *class* method:

```
class tensor:
    n = 1
    def __init__(self, n):
       self.n = n ;

    @classmethod
    def prod(cls,t,sca=1):
       newa = cls(t.n * sca)
       return newa

t1 = tensor(5)
t2 = tensor.prod(t1, 3)
```

The actual class, in this case `tensor`, will be passed as the first parameter in the call to `prod`. Class methods are useful if you need to be able to modify the class's state, which in your example you do not.

Static and class methods are useful for implementing alternate constructor-like methods, which your `prod` function seems to be.

By the way, it is common to name classes with capital letters. Also, the assignment `n = 1` in your class definition does not seem to be serving a useful purpose.